# Application using PowerShell System.Management.Automation compiled on Windows 8 not working on Windows 7

Tags: powershell, windows-7

I built a powershell script runner on windows 8 using VS2012 and Framework 4.0 and when I launch the runner on windows 7 it gives me an error because the powershell version is older that the one on windows 8. (Win7: PS2, Win8 PS3). (System.Management.Automation)

Are there any solutions besides recompiling the application on windows 7 or installing powershell 3 on windows 7? (Or upgrading my windows 7 machine :P) Thanks!

Comment: Have you installed Windows Management Framework 3.0 (PowerShell 3.0) on the win7 machines? See http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595 for download

Comment: Oh, didn't see the last part. Maybe it's possible to simply copy the required dll and manually register it, but I wouldn't recommend it. Best and recommended option: install WMF3.0. It gives you some improved features for management anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the PowerShell 2.0 version of the assembly (v1) from your project on Windows 8. Compiling with that version will make it work on Windows 7 (PowerShell 2.0) and Windows 8 (PowerShell 3.0).

To get the PowerShell v2.0 version of this assembly you could pull it from the GAC or install the [PowerShell 2.0 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2560) and use that.

Also make sure your project targets .Net 3.5 for it to work on Windows 7 without having to install .Net 4.5.